# SQL - ORDER BY - Threads & Messages

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have three tables:

```
Message_Threads: ( thread_ID )
Message_Users:   ( thread_ID, user_ID, notify )
Messages:        ( thread_ID, user_ID, message_ID, date_created )
```

I am trying to list out just the threads in order of most recent message within the thread, but I want to show the ones that have notify=1 above the rest (notify is set to 1 for all other users on a thread when a new message is posted and set to 0 when they visit that thread). Anyone got a monster select statement for me?

Comment: Or if you think restructuring the tables will make things easier, please advise.

Comment: Does this means that you don't want the messages of the thread, only the thread itself, is that correct?, cause then I don't understand the part where you say that the ones that have notify=1 should be above the rest. Can you post an example of what the result would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure does not make clear the relationship be messages and message user.  My assumption is that these are joined on both thread_id and user_id.  This then aggregates them at the thread level:

```
select t.thread_id
from thread t join
     message m
     on t.thread_id = m.thread_id join
     message_users mu
     on m.thread_id = mu.thread_id and
        m.user_id = mu.user_id
group by thread_id
order by max(mu.notify) desc, max(m.date_created) desc
```

The key to this is the final order by.  Order by notify first, but descending so "1" appears before "0" (assuming non-1 value is 0).  Then by date created.

To restrict this to a particular user, use a WHERE statement before the group by:

```
WHERE u.user_id = session_user_id
```